# Returning boolean value from long long differs

Tags: ios, boolean, long-long

In my app I have a function that returns a bool from a long long value `_flightId` which is initially assigned `0`. At some point before calling the function below it is usually assigned a value.

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) long long flightId;

- (BOOL)isReady
{
    return (_flightId);
}
```

The problem is that sometimes, even tough it is assigned a different value than `0`, the function will return `0`.

For example:

if `_flightId` = `92559101` the function will return `1`.

If `_flightId` = `92559104` the function will return `0`.

Can somebody explain this behavior?

Comment: Try changing the return line to: `return _flightId == 0 ? NO : YES;`

Comment: I actually did this, thanks. But I am interested in the background of the problem I explained.

Comment: It's probably an overflow problem. `BOOL` is just a `signed char`. Cramming a `long long` into ` signed char` will cause overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `BOOL` is presumably just defined as an 8 bit int (`char`) so when you return a `long long` you're just getting the low order 8 bits of this. The value `92559104` is `0x5845700` which as you can see has the LS 8 bits all set to zero.

You should do an explicit conversion, e.g.

```
return _flightId != 0;
```

or the idiomatic:

```
return !!_flightId;
```

Comment: That answers it. Thanks!